# Get average of a column at end of row

Tags: mysql, row, average

I have following table:

```
Name Height
A    20
B    30
C    40
```

I need the following output in MySQL as follows:

Name   Height 
A           20 
B           30 
C           40 
 
Average   30

The output should appear at the end of the result of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `ROLLUP` and a trick:

```
select name, avg(height) as height
from table t
group by name with rollup;
```